# Do I need the boot option nvme_load=YES

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, dell, nvme

I have dual booted my system with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Windows 10 Home was pre-installed). I'm using a Dell Inspiron 5593 laptop with an M.2 NVMe 512GB SSD. I followed the official [guide](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000131253/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-windows-8-or-10-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc) posted by Dell for dual-booting, and I noticed that [this one](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-mn/000131901/loading-ubuntu-on-systems-using-pcie-m2-drives) mentions to add the boot option `nvme_load=YES`, however, the screens which were in the guide did not appear in my installation process, and I didn't add that kernel argument. I did everything else as instructed by the guide, including changing the SATA controller to ACHI from RAID (by booting into safe mode in Windows). Secure boot and Fast start-up are both disabled. The second guide which mentions the kernel argument `nvme_loads=YES` also mentions that a problem exists for Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.04; however, I saw that many people had issues in their installation (because of the NVMe) in other forums on the internet, and that they resolved it by adding the boot option `nvme_load=YES`.

After successfully installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and restarting the system twice, I added the boot option when booting (i.e. by clicking 'e' on the 'Ubuntu' option in GRUB), but `sysctl -a` command does not show that the boot option was added.

My system is working well, and I am having no issues with the OS so far (all Windows files can be accessed as well), except that it heats up a bit more than usual, and the fans kick in.

Should I do anything now? Should I add `nvme_load=YES` to the `/etc/default/grub` file? Is it fine to just continue using the it this way?

Any proper responses will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Just my thoughts no errors no problem

Comment: I added nvme_load=YES to the /etc/default/grub file in the variable GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. I thought maybe it would be better, because this was pestering me quite a bit actually :)